# Safari 9.0.2 on OS X crashes on special file-URL

Tags: macos, safari, crash

I've been working with [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/) to author some web pages. When I use the "Browse Page" function it opens the web page with this file-URL: `file:///.file/id=6571367.190169036`. This works fine.

When I click on any of the links on the page browsed the browser crashes.
After a few tests, it seems to crash on any URLs that starts with `file:///.file/`, except for the one URL used by the "Browse Page" function.

I use latest update of OS X Yosemite on a Mac Book Pro.

Any solution to this issue?

---

Update: I can verify that this issue is still present after an upgrade to OS X El Capitan and Safari 9.1

Comment: `file://host/path` … Trying to use  `/.file/` as a fully-qualified host doesn't sound like a good way to proceed. Any file:// ref is going to need that content to be already available on the remote user's machine anyway, so doesn't sound promising for a web site

Comment: Using the file-operator in Safari should work, not crash the app. Chrome brings up a "This webpage is not found" page for the same URL.

Comment: Agreed, it should not crash - yet it does. But... I really do wonder why you think that path ought to work, even on a non-crashing browser. Relying on the contents of a hidden system file on a remote user's machine is not the way to construct a web page

Comment: I will not use the resulting URL shown in Safari for anything else than using the KompoZer App to preview the webpages in Safari. The URLs ref'ed to in the web page I author has relative paths, no absolute paths, so this will not be a problem when pages has been put on a web server.